# Display an alert visible if the user is using the web or not

Tags: javascript, php, web, alert, global

i'm new at programming and im looking for a way to display an alert whenever the user is in the web or not. i've tried with alert() (the one in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) using a timer to test it, but the alert only displays in the tab and not over every application running in the desktop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If there's a solution in other languages i'm open to try them.
thanks.

Comment: First show what you have tried (in form of some code).

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);` I've tried this, but i have already found a possibly answer with [Mozilla developers notification API] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) works really fine 'till now.

Comment: are you talking about desktop notifications from the browser ?

Comment: Yes, sorry if i didn't clreared up. I want to do it from browser. But, testing out some API's i found out that the notification API works really fine doing what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link you've shared, if you want a popup over any desktop application through the browser, use the W3C Notification API. For example

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
};

function notifyMe() {
    if (!Notification) {
        alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
        return;
    }

    if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
        Notification.requestPermission();
    else {
        var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
            icon: 'Notification icon',
            body: "Notification body",
        });

        notification.onclick = function () {};
    }
}
```

and call the `notifyMe()` using the navigator online variable. For example

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (navigator.onLine)
        notifyMe();
}, 1000);
```

This will check whether user is connected to internet every 1 second and display a popup if true.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events